# create a new file by java IO,the file name become "?????"s when I set the file name to Chinese

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

```
File file = new File(this.filePath);
file.createNewFile();
```

I create a file with the code above. I set the `this.filePath` into Chinese and when the file was created, it looks like `?????` in Eclipse.

Here is my dev env:

- MacOS 10.8
- Eclipse 4 juno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try window -> preferences -> general -> workspace, on the rightbar you will see text-file encoding, try other options and see if that fixes your problem.

also make sure your OS supports Chinese language.

Comment: hi, i have set the text file encoding to utf-8, and my mac is sure to support Chinese language... i can rename the file in to Chinese in the finder,but when it comes to creating a new file in the eclipse,it just can't make it....

Comment: try adding to -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclipse.ini, also see http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t93442.rhtml it might help you

Comment: ohhh!!! yess!! that's right... i add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 this element into the eclipse.ini and it really worked out... thank you！